# how efficient is Object type in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, object, memory-management, types

I have dynamic item attributes in a dictionary that could hold either a single or a string or 2 other custom classes.

Right now i store the value in a class that has uninitialized variables for all of these and another variable to say which type to get upon request. I don't like it because it's rather clunky and seems to waste memory (since most of the time the value stored is a single).

I figured i could hold any of these in a single object variable type but i don't know what kind of penalties to expect from this, if any. Should i continue with managing the types myself or let vb figure it out?

Comment: Let the compiler figure it out - not me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you should worry about with the Object type in VB.NET is late-binding. If you call a method on an Object variable (except for those methods that are part of the Object type, such as ToString), the vb runtime has to use reflection to find and call the correct methods on the exact type when they're executed. If you use a specific type for your variable, that lookup will only occur once, when your code is JIT-compiled. I would say that the overhead of late-binding is significant enough that you should avoid it when possible.

However, that doesn't apply to checking the object's type and assigning to a variable with a more specific type. So if you figure out what type of object you have and assign it to the right type of variable before calling methods on it, you should be ok. There is a little bit of overhead to doing that, but it's probably no worse than what you're already doing.

Another reason to avoid late-binding is that it prevents the compiler from doing type checking.